# "No quieres" como "Es que no quieres"

Tags: preguntas

Dada una pregunta de la forma

> *¿No quieres una bebida?*

¿Puede interpretarse como *¿Es que no quieres una bebida?* en algún caso? ¿Se interpreta solamente como *¿Quieres una bebida?*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Español es muy frecuente el uso del interrogativo negativo. Se usa cuando deseas que la respuesta sea la opuesta a lo pedido.

En tu caso preguntar *¿es que no quieres una bebida?* vendría a usarse cuando ya habías preguntado esto, aunque se vería mejor formulado con *es que **acaso***.

De todas formas, cuando preguntas *¿quieres una bebida?* no necesariamente esperas que la respuesta sea lo contrario, pero al anteponer el *no*, naturalmente se espera que sí y rara vez se responde con un rotundo *no.* Compara:

> — ¿No quieres una bebida?
>   — Podría ser.
>
> ---
>
> — ¿Quieres una bebida?
>   — No, gracias. / Quizás más tarde.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Yo añadiría que ¿Es que...? o ¿Es que acaso...? denotan *incredulidad*, lo cual es congruente con lo que has dicho de "cuando ya habías preguntado esto", pero sólo si la respuesta ha sido que no. A: ¿Coca-cola? [ofreciendo un vaso] B: No, gracias. A: [asombrado] ¿Es que no quieres una bebida? Si le hubiese respondido que sí, la segunda pregunta de A habría desconcertado bastante a B.